# How to add checking conditions using with ibatis dynamic query?

Tags: mysql, sql, ibatis

I am using **MSQL** with **Ibatis**. I got a trouble when retrieving datas by checking with dynamic query.

At my Table ..

> Id(Long) | Name(varchar) | Gender (varchar) | Age(Integer) |

and I want to retrieve "Name" filed of

1. If "Gender" == female then ignore age of her and retrieve her age.
2. If "Gender" == male then check his age > 16 . If so , retrieve it.
3. If "Gender" == male and age <= 16 . I don't want to retrieve it.

I want to use dynamic query when gender was "male". There haven't any parameters from calling query.
I really want to do is like that..

```
SELECT NAME FROM PEOPLE WHERE ID > 0
<isNotEqual property="GENDER" compareValue="female">AND AGE > 16</isNotEqual>
```

My questions how to figure it out and has any other ways to get it ? I don't mean only with Ibatis.

Thanks for reading my question. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: This is my sample table and sample conditions. At my real facing problem is I want to join another table by dynamically under conditions of table's column value (that can't be seen).

Answer (score 0):

```
select name, age
from people
where gender = 'male' and age > 16
or gender = 'female'
```

Comment: thanks for imediately response for my question. You point me of my forgotten way. Thanks in advance. How should I do with Ibatis bro ?